# Encrypt password in insert statement in postgresql throws an error (Need to add explicit type cast)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, encryption, casting, password-encryption

New to postgresql. It might be very simple; but am not getting it.

I've this in mysql:

```
insert into APP_USERS VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'adminemailid','', 'System', 'Administrator', 'SysAdmin', 'CompanyName',
sha('password123'), 'ADMIN', 2,'SCREEN',0);
```

After referring postgresql documentations on password encryption/hashing and various similar questions on Stackoverflow;

I tried it's equivalent in postgresql as:

```
insert into APP_USERS VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'adminemailid','', 'System', 'Administrator', 'SysAdmin', 'CompanyName',
crypt('password123',gen_salt('sha1')), 'ADMIN', 2,'SCREEN',0)
```

But; it throws me an error at function `gen_salt()`:

**No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

(The datatype of column(field) password is **character varying**.)

I read various manuals on type casting in postgresql and tried casting the function.

But; no use. I came across various similar errors.

Can I know what exactly am missing? or what is the exact way of type casting?
Or do I need to add chkpass module (extension) for this?

I already have pgcrypto extension and am using postgresql 9.6.

Comment: In the `psql` execute: `\dx pgcrypto` and `show search_path;` so you can ensure that the extension is available for the session. Additionally: `select crypt('password123',gen_salt('sha1'));` answers: `ERROR:  gen_salt: Unknown salt algorithm` just because ["_The accepted types are: des, xdes, md5 and bf._"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. `I ensured that the extension is available for the session.`; I tried with `des, xdes, md5 and bf` algorithms. It still shows me an error: `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`at `gen_salt`; What might be the reason? Or `What kind of type casting I need?` Any idea?
-- Thanks :)

Comment: By the way; I'll be back with some Research on this :)

Comment: Provide the results of the all three commands from the my first comment. BTW there are two questions: 1) Why the extension don't works? 2) How to encrypt a password? For the second one: you could to use the "built-in" [`md5` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) instead of MySQL's `sha`.

Comment: I created the extension using `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto`; command and am able to see it.
When I run; `\dx pgcrypto`; it gives me `syntax error at or near "\"`
(Am sorry; I didn't understand what it will do. :D)
`show search_path`; will show me schema name `my_schema`
and `select crypt('password123',gen_salt('sha1'));` gives me:
`No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts` at `gen_salt`. By the way,  `md5 function` encrypts the password; I shall look it as an alternative.
Thanks :)

Comment: I got here something:  http://superuser.com/questions/1046751/pgcrypto-extension-is-installed-but-its-functions-are-not-available;
Guess I shall `add UUID random number generator gen_random_uuid() to pgcrypto`; Will experiment with it :)

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Thank You for this. I'll do little research on `HMAC`, `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions

Answer (score 5):

It is not the answer actually but a brief explanation how to find the source of the error.

First of all lets find the `pgcrypto` extension:

```
select e.extname, n.nspname
from pg_catalog.pg_extension e left join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = e.extnamespace;
```

It should return something like:

```
╔════════════════════╤════════════╗
║      extname       │  nspname   ║
╠════════════════════╪════════════╣
║ plpgsql            │ pg_catalog ║
║ adminpack          │ pg_catalog ║
║ plpythonu          │ pg_catalog ║
║ pg_stat_statements │ public     ║
║ plpython3u         │ pg_catalog ║
║ hstore             │ public     ║
║ uuid-ossp          │ public     ║
║ pg_trgm            │ public     ║
║ ltree              │ public     ║
║ tablefunc          │ public     ║
║ unaccent           │ public     ║
║ pgcrypto           │ nd         ║
╚════════════════════╧════════════╝
```

So the `pgcrypto` installed in the schema `nd` in the my database.

Next lets look to the `search_path` parameter which provide the information where to search DB objects:

```
show search_path;
╔═════════════════╗
║   search_path   ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ "$user", public ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

It means that the objects will be searched in the schema with name of the current user and, if nothing found, in the schema `public`.

Finally lets check the current user:

```
select current_user;
╔══════════════╗
║ current_user ║
╠══════════════╣
║ postgres     ║
╚══════════════╝
```

So as you can see the extension installed in the schema `nd` can not be found using the `search_path` which actually is `postgres, public` and we got the error:

```
select gen_salt('md5');
ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select gen_salt('md5');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

There are several ways how to fix it depending of the actual values for your DB mentioned above.

You can move the extension to another schema like:

```
alter extension pgcrypto set schema public;
```

You can change the `search_path` option like:

```
set search_path to '"$user", public'; -- for the active session only
alter database your_db_name set search_path to '"$user", public'; -- permanently for the database
```

Finally you could to explicitly specify the schema in the SQL statement:

```
select schema_where_it_installed.gen_salt('md5');
-- For my example:
select nd.gen_salt('md5');
```

Comment: Thank You for this. +1
Though; all other queries work fine;  `select my_schema.gen_salt('md5');` 
Gives `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` (on `my_schema`)
Am checking with this.